# Chart.js chart keeps drawing repeatedly

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Hi so I'm working on a doughnut chart with `chart.js` and I'm calling `.destroy` on it as I need to display multiple charts with different datasets. But now my chart keeps flickering and drawing itself repeatedly. I have already declared myChart with `let myChart = null;`

```
if (myChart != null) {
    myChart.destroy();
}
      
myChart = new Chart(document.getElementById('defaultCanvas0'), config);
```

**This is how it looks like:**

[Doughnut Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wa3Bk.jpg)

It keeps flickering and I want it to display properly each time I switch between the options in the dropdown at the bottom left (The countries)

Comment: it's your code, which you haven't shown.

Comment: Without a reproducable sample this is not possible to help since we don't know if you call anything in loops what is the only explanation for this

Comment: look into : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45706830/chart-js-mouseover-causes-graphs-to-flicker-and-resize

Comment: this is called in my draw function